# JSON query with Snowflake

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hello I have the below json field (addressbooklist) in which im trying to extract addr1 however my code results are NULL
Can someone help?

Query-

```
select 
addressbooklist:addressbook.addressbookAddress.addr1 as test,
from customer;
```

JSON Field

```
{
  "addressbook": [
    {
      "addressbookAddress": {
        "addr1": "701 N. Brand Boulevard",
        "addr2": null,
        "addr3": null,
        "addrPhone": null,
        "addrText": "Executive Software International<br>701 N. Brand Boulevard<br>Glendale CA 912031242<br>United States",
        "addressee": "Executive Software International",
        "attention": null,
        "city": "Glendale",
        "country": {
          "value": "_unitedStates"
        },
        "customFieldList": null,
        "internalId": null,
        "nullFieldList": null,
        "override": false,
        "state": "CA",
        "zip": "912031242"
      },
      "defaultBilling": false,
      "defaultShipping": true,
      "internalId": "1587207",
      "isResidential": false,
      "label": "701 N. Brand Boulevard"
    },
    {
      "addressbookAddress": {
        "addr1": "701 N. Brand Boulevard",
        "addr2": null,
        "addr3": null,
        "addrPhone": null,
        "addrText": "Executive Software International<br>701 N. Brand Boulevard<br>Glendale CA 912031242<br>United States",
        "addressee": "Executive Software International",
        "attention": null,
        "city": "Glendale",
        "country": {
          "value": "_unitedStates"
        },
        "customFieldList": null,
        "internalId": null,
        "nullFieldList": null,
        "override": false,
        "state": "CA",
        "zip": "912031242"
      },
      "defaultBilling": true,
      "defaultShipping": false,
      "internalId": "1587208",
      "isResidential": false,
      "label": "701 N. Brand Boulevard"
    }
  ],
  "replaceAll": false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `JSON` object you refered to has the following structure:

```
Array[Object1{key1: value, key2: value}, Object2{key1: value, key2: value}]
```

`Object1` is the first item of your array with the index 0, `Object2` has index 1 and so on.

You access an item of an array like `Array[0]` and you can reach a value inside an object like `Object1.key1`. In this example you would reach out to `key1` like `Array[0]Object1.key1`.

In your case you can access `addr1` in you first object like this:

```
addressbook[0].addressbookAddress.addr1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your json document `addressbook` element is an array, not a plain property. You can reference a specific element in an array with `[0]` notation (0=first element, 1=second,...). Your query would look like this:

```
select addressbooklist:addressbook[0].addressbookAddress.addr1 as test from customer;
```

If you want to have all of the addressbook items in the result, you can flatten the json structure with this kind of query:

```
select ab.value:addressbookAddress.addr1 as test
from customer
, lateral flatten(input => addressbooklist:addressbook) ab;
```

Result:

```
TEST
"701 N. Brand Boulevard"
"701 N. Brand Boulevard"
```

More info on Snowflake json syntax for arrays can be found here:

- Get single array items: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-semistructured.html#retrieving-a-single-instance-of-a-repeating-element
- Flatten function to get table from array:
  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-semistructured.html#using-the-flatten-function-to-parse-arrays

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know which language you want to use. I just have to do this with mySQL.  Something like this may help:

select
yourField->>'$."addressbookAddress"[0].addr1' as address
from yourTable
where 1